# TeamCity : project parameters inheritance issue?

Tags: parameters, dependencies, teamcity

I have a TeamCity 8.0.3 project with multiple configs inside which have a common parameter (defined as a project parameter) : `targetServerIP`. One of these configs is a "*1 click deployment*" which starts others configs by using snapshots dependencies. I've set the parameter as "prompt" so the IP is asked on each run of any configs, this is what

**Problem :**
Individually it works fine, on each config run the IP is asked and successfully applied to the config. But when I execute the "*1 clic deployment*" it also asks the IP but does not transmit it to other dependants configs (the value stays `<empty>`).

**My question :** How can I set this parameter to be applyed to others configs when it is prompted ?

PS : I've obviously tried to set it as an `env.` parameter but it does not helps.

PS2 : Using templates does not seems to be a good solution for me.

Comment: I never tried this, but it looks to me like a TeamCity 8.0 bug as I read through what you written.

Comment: I don't know, it seems impossible that it only appends to me...

Comment: I am having this same problem and still can't find the answer.  Seems like a bug to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are 2 problems.  One I can help with, <strike>one I am trying to solve myself</strike> just solved myself.

Your problem is how you setup the chain.  The *1 click deployment* "depends" on the others.

It **cannot** pass parameters to the other builds.
It **can** use parameters from the dependent builds by *dep.dependent_build_configuration.paramter_name*.

## The fix

There are 2 things you have to do.

1. Setup artifact dependencies
2. Setup triggers

---

### Build A

#### - Parameters

GlobalParameter

- **Display**: Normal
- **Type**: Text
- **Allowed Value**: Not Empty

### Build B

#### - Parameters

LocalParameter

- **Display**: hidden
- **Type**: Text
- **Value** %dep.Build_A_GlobalParemeter%

#### - Snapshot Dependency

- **Depends on**: "Build A"

#### - Triggers

- **TriggerType**: Finish Build Trigger
- **Build Configuration**: Build A

---

## How this works

The **artifact dependency** makes the variables available via the *%dep.Build_A.GlobalParameter%* syntax.  The **Finish Build Trigger** causes *Build A* to trigger *Build B*.  You will have access to the parameters because they are saved from the previous build.

Comment: Thanks, had the exact same problem at work and your solution fixed it.

Comment: Unfortunately I have no more access to this TC project so I can not test but it should work, thank you ! (PS: Wow exactly 365-1 days after my question lol)

Answer (score 0):

Until today (1 month) I've not found where the problem is (many days lost in investigation), the only workaround is to manually change value of parameter each time I need to.

Maybe there is something special to do with the XML config files ? I don't know.

Answer (score 0):

In completion to @Brandon's response, you may achieve what you wanted to do in the first place using the TeamCity RestAPI you may call resulting properties on a build ID to see what properties were set on the build.

```
curl my.teamcityserver.com/app/rest/builds/<some-parent-build-id>/resulting-properties
```

search the parameter name you need in the XML and you should be able to get the value from the parent build.